# How do I build a device to pull items upwards?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make a quarry, as in some quarries I've seen you can pull items with a device which is upstairs.

I've read about the dropper elevator, but that one has the redstone circuits downstairs for working, I want the device working UPSTAIRS.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Try using command blocks. Almost anything is possible with command blocks

Comment: Could you show us the example of what you don't want, so we can try to reverse it and give you what you do want?

Comment: A quick search on Google does wonders. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=minecraft%20elevator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try mine carts because those don't have circuits up or downstairs and if you build them in a spiral it can save some space. Another way to do it is with a hopper elevator which I'm not an expert at making. I would also recommend this video for yet another option.

you would have to modify LogDotZip's design by taking away the lava and blocks at the top so you could move items to a new location and you would have to put a piston running on a redstone clock at the top that pushes items into a hopper so you can automatically get the items into a chest.

These are the best ways of moving blocks upward in Minecraft. Hope this helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If items are in blocks, they tend to go upwards. With this mechanic, it's possible to make a item elevator just by placing blocks above it. I am not sure how to actually pull up items rather than push.

Answer (score -4):

For a Normal moving elevator you would use the clone command from 1.8
For a stairs elevator you can watch a Youtube video on how to make a stairs
elevator.

Comment: Telling someone to watch a Youtube video is very unhelpful.  Which video?  Likewise, telling someone to use a command without an example is also not useful.